# What Tools/Projects will allow the capture of HTTP requests/response in IIS and Apache

Tags: c#, .net, linux, apache, iis

I am thinking an HttpModules for IIS, a Pre and Post request handler and some custom module for Apache.

Please only suggest Open Source, we will need to modify the projects.

We want to run these on our high volume production systems so tools that emphasise debugging is not what we are looking for. We want the simplest capture paradigm.

We want to capture data for particular web sites, not for interfaces so I am not looking at packet sniffers.

We would prefer an in-process solution which means avoiding wire-shark, squid or other proxy based solutions.

A nice to have would be the ability to replay a stream of requests in another environment, but I am confident we can build this ourselves if we can capture the requests in a sensible manner.

Any ideas, suggestions and questions will gladly be entertained.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy server that logs is best, but you've already ruled that out.  Outside of that, you need a product per web server.  For IIS, yes, an HttpModule is the way to go.  To replay them, that's likely a carefully crafted log viewer.  This is typically a feature of a proxy server.  Even Fiddler has the ability to capture and replay.